# Getting the right file extension after converting multiple files with FFMPEG

Tags: bash, macos, find

I have a script to convert `*.flac` to `*.mp3`. The conversion happens as it should, but the files always end up with the extension `*.flac.mp3` instead of just `*.mp3`.

```
find . -name "*.flac" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -vsync 0 -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 0 -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 {}.mp3 \;
```

I already tried putting `${i%.*}.mp3` in the output field, but that only leads to the creation of a file called just `.mp3` with nothing before the extension at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The program you are using is `find` not `bash`. You can not tell `find` to interpret `bash`'s parameter expansions.

Comment: @ceving The  [tag:bash] tag is still relevant, as the solution might include calling out to the shell.

Comment: Alsok, the [tag:macos] tag is relevant because it implies what version of `find` it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{}` is the complete filename as found by `find`, including the `.flac` extension. To manipulate it, you can call a shell in `-exec`:

```
find . -name '*.flac' \
    -exec bash -c '
        for f; do
            ffmpeg -i "$f" -vsync 0 -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 0 \
                -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 "${f%.flac}".mp3
        done
    ' _ {} +
```

This uses the `-exec <cmd> {} +` syntax to run `<cmd>` once<sup>1</sup> with all files appended; the command itself is of the form

```
bash -c 'for f; do <something>; done' _
```

where `for f` loops over all files supplied as parameters; `_` is a dummy parameter to be used as `$0` within `bash -c`.

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, "as few times as possible while respecting command line length limitations".

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I had been trying to do. I don't think I would ever have figured it out by myself, but I understand when I look at your answer.